# Computer Models of E Coli / Saccharomyces cerevisiae metabolite pathways

Tags: molecular-biology, protein-expression

Are there mathematical models one can use to predict the expression levels of a foreign gene inserted into a well studied host organism like  E Coli or S cerevisiae?

I'm not, obviously, looking for some magical, accurate in silicio model; but even an approximate heuristic. e.g. Before starting a cloning experiment to estimate levels of a secondary metabolite expression in different organisms that both contain the substrate natively but may have it in different levels.

Alternatively, can the math models help in estimating which other competing pathways may be draining away a precursor of interest so that a rational attempt can be made to block such pathways to promote selective expression of the metabolite of interest.

Of course, the cloning experiment is the gold standard but are there ways to simulate a part of this and reduce the dead ends of experiments. Is there standard software I ought to be looking at?

Comment: Yes there are Flux Balance models but you would have to incorporate your gene into the metabolic network..

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks! Can you offer any pointers on where  / what software to start with? What sort of parameters would one need to introduce an ad hoc gene into an existing flux balance model?

Comment: I don't actually know a great deal about this but you would have to introduce new reactions in your metabolic network which might consume some primary metabolites and produce your desired secondary metabolite and by-products. You can then calculate the flux balance that can maximize the secondary metabolite production. This is basically a linear programming problem. There are some optimized programs for this but I don't have much idea. You can start by reading some basic books on flux balance analysis.